# Can't push view onto stack

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a view controller:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
```

It displays a map and pins are dropped onto this map.  When the user tap's the accessory button one of the annotation views I want *another* view to be pushed in front of the user.

For some or other reason the navigation controller is always null when I run the following code.

```
hotelDetailViewController = [[HotelDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HotelDetailViewController"
                                                                        bundle:nil];

if (![self navigationController])
{
    NSLog(@"navigation controller null");
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:hotelDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong?  At what point to do I need to alloc and init the navigation controller because it seems to be read only?

Comment: need some more code to show context, where is navigationController defined?

Comment: @Aaron it's a property of `UIViewController`

Comment: I'm guessing that the view controller handling the action is not actually inside a navigation controller. Maybe your DetailViewController is embedded from somewhere else but not via a navigation controller method? more details about this event would be nice.

Comment: @Max kinda what I was saying, but not as specific...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At what point to do I need to alloc and init the navigation controller because it seems to be read only?

Well, you don't usually set the `navigationController` property yourself, you would typically have a navigation controller set up from the start and then pass your `DetailViewController` to the navigation controller, and that's when the property is set.

The section in the View Controllers programming guide about [Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html) explains how you should set up your navigation controller, either with a nib file or programmatically.